# How long does it take for a projectile with the speed-time equation $y=x^2 + 2$ to reach speed $15$ m/s?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, physics, projectile-motion

I've been given the following equation to graph, plus a couple of sub-problems I need to solve, and I'm having trouble solving one of them. A quick summary of the problem:

> A speeding projectile observed at time $0$ can be represented by the graph $y = x^2 + 2$ for the range of $-2$ seconds to $4$ seconds.
> a) Plot the graph (already done).
> b) How long does it take to reach speed $15$ m/s.

It is b) that I'm having the problem with. I thought this would be as simple as taking the equation and turning it into
\begin{align*}
15 &= x^2 + 2\\
13 & = x^2\\
\sqrt{13} & = 3.61\\
x & = 3.61
\end{align*}

But I'm not sure if I am doing this right. Am I missing something here, or is this correct? $X$ and $Y$ represent time and speed, respectively.

Comment: What do $y$ and $x$ represent?

Comment: I've changed [tag:algebra] tag to [tag:algebra-precalculus], since we don't use algebra tag anymore, see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/473/the-use-of-the-algebra-tag/3081#3081) for details.

Comment: x is time, y is speed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your problem, you stated that y is the speed in m/s of the projectile and x is the time elapsed. Given those conditions, your solution would be correct. It merely asks at what x value (time) is the speed (y value) equal to 15 m/s, so you just solve the equation for for 15 m/s and that's it. I assume that the starting time is x = 0 because you said is observed a time 0.

Comment: @ copper.hat He states in the bottom of his problem that y is speed  and x is time so I don't think you need to take the derivative here as it isn't the position-time graph. Furthermore, this is supposed to be an algebra question so I'm guessing no calculus required.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that $y$ represents the position and $x$ the time. If this is the case, then the speed would be given by $\frac{d y}{dx} = 2 x$. So, the required speed is reached when $\frac{d y}{dx} = 15$, or $x=7.5$. How long it takes depends on the initial time, so the answer is $7.5-x_0$, where $x_0$ is the initial time.

However, this is a guess, since I do not know what $x$ and $y$ represent.

Comment: He is trying to solve for $x$, which should imply that $x$ is the time.

Comment: It would suggest, but not imply, that $x$ is time. $y$ could be either position or speed, and the initial time was not specified. So, my answer is still in the realm of a guess...